# Returns maximum distance from lat and long distance

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, math

Filter cafes in response to those within distance (km) radius of provided lat/lng coords.

I'm currently able to get the lat and long distance to add to my query param in my api but I want to add a **maxdistance** from the "user" which I'm not 100% sure how to calculate yet. Currently it gets the minimum distance.

```
            Point currentLocation = null;
            if (latitude.HasValue && longitude.HasValue)
            {
                currentLocation = new Point(latitude.Value, longitude.Value)
                {
                    SRID = 4326
                };
                cafe = cafe.Where(w => w.Latitude.HasValue && w.Longitude.HasValue);
            }
           //gets minimum distance to user
           //want to get maximum distance from user
           Distance = currentLocation != null ? currentLocation.Distance(new Point(s.Latitude.Value, s.Longitude.Value)) : 0
```

Comment: What does max distance between two points mean? If I drive in circles I can drive hundreds of kilometres / miles to get 5 streets away.

Comment: Max distance in my head I'm assuming like a radius like lets say x user is at latitude=-36.850245&longitude=174.763544 and they type in the param 10 (km) then I would expect the api to return every cafe within a 10 km radius of the user

Comment: @James McCoy Take minimum distance to each cafe and if it is smaller than 10km you return it?

Comment: @JonasH Would I still be able to use the .Distance() method? I'm just confused how to add "maxDistance" as a variable

Comment: @James McCoy If the user should specify the maxDistance then it should be a parameter to the method.